# BlueImp Upload from iphone 1.2 GB size

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

i tried to pick a file from iphone photomediathek with 1,2 GB.

Before uploading, the iphone converts the file, then the upload starts briefly and stops immediately, presumably when determining the size of the file.

In the post() function tries:

```
$content_range_header = $this->get_server_var('HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE');
```

No value is returned here either.

PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
....
$uploaded_bytes = $this->fix_integer_overflow((int)$content_range[1]);

Does anyone know the problem when uploading with iPhone?

Thanks for hints

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is the phone, more likely that you're trying to upload a 1.2Gb file. If you would like some constructive help, then please add all the relevant client and server side code to the question, and more details about the exact issue. Right now there is no useful information for anyone to debug.

Comment: 1. capture a video that is at least 1.5GByte big (e.g. UHD, 60FPS, 2:30 minutes)

2. open local demo from https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ - edit the max file size to unlimited

3. select captured video from photo mediathek (1. Option) by clicking "add files....)

4. iPhone starts to prepare file for about 2-3 minutes

5. after preparation, the selected file is shown for about 2-3 seconds in Safari before the UI is reloaded ans reseted

Comment: This behaviour only exists on iPhone, probably because of the long preparation the phone is performing. Shorter movies with shorter preparation time, are accepted